# Parsing a string like "03/2020" to a DateTime variable

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have to parse a string, which always look like `03/2020` (so the format is `MM/yyyy`), to a DateTime variable.

How do I achieve it the most proper way? (Without splitting the string into substrings)

I already found the `DateTime.ParseExact` function, but I'm confused by the third parameter (culture-specific format information).

Is the `DateTime.ParseExact` the way to go or is there a better function/way to achieve the goal?

```
var inputString = "03/2020";
var inputStringFormat = @"MM/yyyy";

// var inputStringAsDateTime = ???
```

**Edit 1**

As additional info I have to say, that the string (`inputString`) is read from a barcode. So the separator in it is always the `/`.

Tim Schmelter explained in his answer, how to mask such separators.
It looks like I have to change my `inputStringFormat` variable to:

```
var inputStringFormat = @"MM'/'yyyy";
```

Comment: Why don't you use `03/expecteddate/2020`and parse?

Comment: That's not a *date* format. You can't have a DateTime without a *day*. How do you intend to use this? You could use a DateTime that points to the first day in a month by prepending `1/`. Or you may need to find the end of the month. Or use a custom class entirely

Comment: `DateTime` expects a day, it might be better to make a `MonthYear` class and add your own parser into it.

Comment: What confuses you? Did you research the parameter?

Comment: @Justcode: I'm refactoring some old code. The string formatted like `MM/yyyy` is read from a barcode

Comment: @Alexxus you can concatenate the string,

Answer (score 1):

If the first day of the month is good for you, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, inputStringFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, i use ToDateTime method of Convert class. I have **tested** it, it's working.

```
string inputString = "03/2020";
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(inputString));
```

It will give output like 3/1/2020 12:00:00 AM means it will gives you output according to your system's date format.

Answer (score 0):

With such simple date format you can use

```
var inputArr = inputString.split(@"/");
var inputStringAsDateTime = new DateTime(inputArr[0], inputArr[1], 1);
```

however for culture you can use constant

```
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```